# AG-Grid: How to use custom filters with infinite row model

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using AG Grid Angular and would like to use **custom filters** in combination with the **infinite row model**.

The [documentation of the custom filters](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-filter/) does not mention the infinite row model, so it is not clear whether the two are compatible or not. I have implemented the "simple filter" example from the documentation and attached it to my grid, and here is what I observe:

- The custom filter is properly displayed and clicking the radio button refreshes the grid.
- However, the data is not modified and the `doesFilterPass()` method of the custom filter does not seem to ever be called (which would not make sense in the infinite row model).
- My row model's datasource's `getRows()` method is called, but `params.filterModel` remains empty.

It seems to me that this almost works, except that the custom filter needs to either:

- tell the grid to add a filter model that the datasource can process
- or tell the datasource directly to apply a filter (this seems possible, because the filter can access the datasource via `params.rowModel.datasource`, but this seems like a hack)

Is there a proper way to do that, which I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Infinite Row Model, the grid expects you to handle the filtering of the data yourself and return the filtered rows in the `getRows` callback, as documented here: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/infinite-scrolling/#sorting--filtering

Please see the following sample which shows you how to use a Custom Filter Component to Filter Rows on the Age Column: https://plnkr.co/edit/riKeOvcWdUwWioVs

Inside the `getModel` callback, you simply return a value / object which will be passed by the grid as `request.filterModel` inside `getRows`:

```
  getModel(): any {
    if (this.filterValue === 'all') {
      return null;
    } else {
      return {
        filter: this.filterValue,
        type: 'equals',
      };
    }
  }
```

Then inside `getRows` I've written some basic functionality to filter the data:

```
          getRows: function (params) {
            console.log(
              'asking for ' + params.startRow + ' to ' + params.endRow
            );
            setTimeout(function () {
              var dataAfterFiltering = filterData(data, params.filterModel);
              var rowsThisPage = dataAfterFiltering.slice(
                params.startRow,
                params.endRow
              );
              var lastRow = -1;
              if (dataAfterFiltering.length <= params.endRow) {
                lastRow = dataAfterFiltering.length;
              }
              params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
            }, 500);
          },
```